# Alias/script to log the command history before exiting terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, script

I'm new to `bash` and scripting.

I was thinking of writing an alias or a script so that every time I `exit` the command line, it will record my command history. Because I try a lot of new commands, and I would like to go back to the file and make comments to it, so I can learn better and not just try the commands and then forget them completely.

```
alias exit ="history > `date +%Y-%m-%d`.txt; exit"
```

but when I reload my bash, I get:

```
-bash: alias: exit: not found
-bash: alias: =history > 2015-09-22.txt; exit: not found
```

Why doesn't this work? Should I try to write a script with a while loop instead?

Comment: By the way, the error is caused by the fact that you have a space before the `=` in your `alias` command; it should be `alias exit="history …"`.

Answer (score 6):

Bash has a history file that you are probably looking for. Try `vim ~/.bash_history` or `cat ~/.bash_history`. It'll probably be what you are looking for. That is the history file location for redhat distros, might be located elsewhere for other distros... but the home directory makes sense for it :)

Comment: The history file is automatically read at `bash` startup (if it exists) so the commands from your previous session(s) can be reused with `!` and seen with `history`. There are limits on the number of lines kept in memory and written to the history file, both defaulting to 1000 but changeable; if you exceed the limit(s) the oldest lines are discarded.

Answer (score 4):

Trim the space before the equals sign:

```
alias exit="history > `date +%Y-%m-%d`.txt; exit"
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129923/bash-run-command-before-a-script-exits). It looks like in bash you can set "traps" to be called when events happen. Try putting this is your .bashrc:

```
function show_history {
    history > `date +%Y-%m-%d`.txt
}
trap show_history EXIT
```

run `help trap` for more information.